# px in constructor function not showing in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a div into the html through a JS constructor function and jquery code.

the pixel element, even if defined, seems to be ignored by the html.

please, can you tell me where is the mistake?

```
function Square(width, height){
  this.width = width +"px";
  this.height = height +"px";
  this.background = "pink";
}

var secondSquare = new Square (100,100, "pink");


$(".btn-new-square").on('click',function() {
// console.log("pink sq");
$("body").append('<div id="newSquare">sdfghjkjhgf</div>');
// console.log('newSquare');
//$("#newSquare").append(secondSquare);
//$("#newSquare").addClass('newSquare');
console.log(secondSquare.height);
console.log(secondSquare.width);
console.log(secondSquare.background);
$("#newSquare").css({
"heigth": secondSquare.heigth,
"width": secondSquare.width,
"background-color": secondSquare.background });

});
```

Comment: Its working fine for me

Comment: Please check here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJzgzz?editors=1111

Comment: It's `height`, not `heigth`...

Comment: If you are saying for second time then it will not work because you are using Id $("*#newSquare*").css()

Comment: I think you don't need to specify px, just put the number as number not as string. Like css({width:50})

Comment: Your *height* spelling is mistake

Comment: hey @SourabhSomani to me it is showing just ad pink text background.. what I am trying to do is to have a 100px x 100px square.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused, what does `secondSquare` have to do with your HTML, you can't append an instance of a class to HTML ?

Comment: @adeneo my secondSquare is a variable  part of my JS file. it is the new square created from the construction Square above. I use that  secondSquare to pass information in my jquery code to build the square by adding the div to html and css class.

Comment: But why, it makes no sense to have a class that just inserts some numbers on click, and you can't append an instance of that class anyway? Why not something that makes sense, like -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/pmn5boc0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spelled height wrong here: `"heigth": secondSquare.heigth`

In both the attribute name and the property name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function Square(width, height,color){
  this.width = width +"px";
  this.height = height +"px";
  this.background = color;
}

var secondSquare = new Square (100,100, "pink");


$(".btn-new-square").on('click',function() {

$("body").append('<div id="newSquare">sdfghjkjhgf</div>');



console.log(secondSquare.height);
console.log(secondSquare.width);
console.log(secondSquare.background);
$("#newSquare").css({
"height": secondSquare.height,
"width": secondSquare.width,
"background-color": secondSquare.background });

});
```

function Square(width, height,color)//here Now I have added 3 parameter

"height": secondSquare.height,//height spelling was mistake

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJzgzz?editors=1111